# Using Tor behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid, tor

i'd like to use TOR/polipo behind a proxy like below

ME --> POLIPO --> TOR --> PROXY SQUID --> WEB

Couldn't find how to do that. When specifying a parent proxy for polipo, it goes straight for it without using TOR so my IP Adress doesn't change.

Please any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For squid:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TheOnionRouter/SquidProxy

For generic HTTP proxies

http://groups.google.com/group/alt.privacy.anon-server/browse_thread/thread/4e75c571154d1004?pli=1

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TheOnionRouter/TorFAQ#MyInternetconnectionrequiresanHTTPproxy.

i believe is what you're looking for.

I use tor over a vpn, but i've never used it with an http proxy

Comment: The first link is dead and the apparent title `SquidProxy` no longer in the wiki, but there's https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO which appears like a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done.

I use browser -> squid -> polipo -> tor -> web

The only thing is that squid doesn't transparently proxy HTTPS.

To do this, set polipo as the parent cache in squid using the cache_peer.

```
cache_peer parent. polipo_ip polipo_port icp_port proxy-only default
```